# Сравнение объектов в List

Tags: java, list

У меня есть List объектов:

```
   {
      "rn": "14",
      "time": "2020-06-16 16:47:55",
      "id": 42332392988,
      "termname": "S1160AFB",
      "type": "100",
      "trancode": "110",
      "pan": "4790729949581839",
      "amount": "360.96",
      "approvalcode": "44444"
    },
    {
      "rn": "15",
      "time": "2020-06-16 16:48:55",
      "id": 42330308379,
      "termname": "S1160AFB",
      "type": "100",
      "trancode": "110",
      "pan": "4149510064617121",
      "amount": "360.96",
      "approvalcode": "55555"
    },
    {
      "rn": "13",
      "time": "2020-06-16 16:49:11",
      "id": 42332530886,
      "termname": "S1160AFB",
      "type": "420",
      "trancode": "110",
      "pan": "4790729949581839",
      "amount": "360.96",
      "approvalcode": "44444"
    }
```

Задача:

1. Найти объекты у которых одинаковый approvalcode. (Он уникальный и может повторяться только 2 раза)
2. Если объекта два и у второго у которого дата позже чем у первого в поле type значение 420.
   То удалить эти оба объекта из list.

Мое решение:

1. Сортирую list по полю approvalcode и дате.

```
     List<Transaction> filteredTrans = transResponse.getTransaction().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Transaction::approvalcode).thenComparing(Transaction::getTime))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

2. Сравниваю по два объекты и удаляю если они выполняют необходимое мне условие.

```
int j = 1;
for (int i=0; i<filteredTrans.size()-1; i++) {
if (filteredTrans.get(i).getApprovalcode().equals(filteredTrans.get(j).getApprovalcode()) && filteredTrans.get(j).getType().equals("420")) {
        filteredTrans.remove(i);
        filteredTrans.remove(j);
        j++;
    }
```

Но вторая часть выглядит как по мне ужасно. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, адекватное решение.

Comment: Неважно, как она выглядит. Она просто неправильная.

Comment: `Он уникальный и может повторяться только 2 раза` то есть не уникальный

Comment: `Сортирую list по полю approvalcode и дате.` почему бы не группировать по `approvalcode` вместо сортировки?

Comment: @tym32167, Я имел в виду что он будет или уникальный или повторится максимум еще один раз. То есть собрать их в Map по полю approvalcode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Transaction> filteredTrans = transResponse.getTransaction().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Transaction::getApprovalcode))
        .values()
        .stream()
        .filter(l -> {
            if (l.size() == 1) return true;
            Transaction maxTimeTr = l.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Transaction::getTime)).orElseThrow();
            return !maxTimeTr.getType().equals("420");
        })
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `Если объекта два и у второго у которого дата позже чем у первого в поле type значение 420` то есть если у первого (у которого дата раньше) 420, то это норм я так пнял.

Comment: `.map(transactions -> transactions.get(0))` такого требования вроде нет

Comment: @tym32167 вроде поправил

Comment: я бы сделал немного по другому, но вцелом вроде ок. Плюсик от меня.

Comment: @tym32167 только у меня сомнение, можно ли сравнивать так дату формата `yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss` через обычное сравнение строк?

Comment: это вроде 24 часовой формат, то есть он должен идти в лексикографическом порядке. Например, что то типа такого используют при хранении [даты в dynamodb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30713517/312041)